# Error in R code for Reddit sentiment analysis

Tags: r, sentiment-analysis, reddit

I am trying to so a Reddit sentiment analysis in R.  I cannot get past an error and I am trying to troubleshoot the problem.

```
# Getting Reddit Data

links<-   find_thread_urls(
  keywords = "Ghostbusters",
  sort_by = "top",
  subreddit = NA,
  period = "all"
)

# function to iterate through all posts

funct = function(i){
  
  content = get_thread_content()(links$URL[i])
  
  com = iconv(content$comment, to = 'utf-8')
  
  clov = get_nrc_sentiment(com)
  
  x1 = 100*colSums(clov)/sum(clov)
  
  return(cbind(links[i,], t(x1) ))
  
}

# list of all the links

ls = 1:nrow(links)

# loop through all the links and bind to a data frame

res = do.call("rbind", lapply(ls, funct))
```

When I run this code, I get this error:

```
Error in lapply(urls, parse_thread_url) : 
argument "urls" is missing, with no default
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: The error message is quite self-explanatory. The function ``parse_thread_url`` requires an argument ``url`` and you haven't supplied it one.

Answer (score 0):

There were few typos in the code,

```
links = find_thread_urls(
  keywords = "Ghostbusters",
  sort_by = "top",
  subreddit = NA,
  period = "all"
)
x0 = vector()
funct = function(i){
  content = get_thread_content(links$url[i])
  com = iconv(content$comment, to = 'utf-8')
  clov = get_nrc_sentiment(com)
  x1 = 100*colSums(clov)/sum(clov)
  x1 = cbind(x0, t(x1))
  return(x1)
}

ls = 1:nrow(links)
res = lapply(ls, funct)
res = do.call(rbind, res)
         anger anticipation  disgust     fear       joy  sadness surprise     trust negative positive
 [1,] 7.276119     8.955224 6.156716 9.514925  6.156716 9.328358 3.731343  9.701493 18.28358 20.89552
 [2,] 5.586592    11.731844 4.469274 6.145251 12.290503 8.379888 5.586592 14.525140 10.61453 20.67039
 [3,] 7.333333     9.238095 5.238095 8.952381  8.095238 6.571429 4.952381 11.523810 16.95238 21.14286
 [4,] 8.641975     6.790123 8.024691 7.098765  8.333333 8.024691 5.555556 11.111111 16.35802 20.06173
```

Comment: This worked.  I really appreciate it so much!  Thank you!